# Will jQuery's html() function reliably execute any contained scripts without weird side effects?

Tags: jquery

it appears in some limited testing i've done - that if I load a document with jQuery using `.ajax()` and then add it to the DOM with `.html(data)` that any SCRIPT tag contained in the HTML document will be executed.

I'm just not sure if this is behavior I can count on? will all browsers do this? am i going to get into trouble if i'm defining any variables in that block that get overwritten later by subsequent refreshing of that part of the DOM?

**Edit:** Just to clarify the javascript in question is just dynamic data expressed in JSON.

Comment: If your intention is to overwrite the previously parsed variables with newer values, then you should be fine, otherwise you will need another solution.

Comment: i was thinking <script>UpdateMyData({"cat":"tiddles"}, "dog":"rover");</script>

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend separating your javascript from your markup, and using [`$.getScript`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript) instead, to be on the safe side, e.g.:

```
$.get("blah.html", function(html) {
    $.getScript("blahscript.js", function(){
      alert("Script loaded and executed.");
      $("#myDiv").html(html);
    });
});
```